# Importing many components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, components

as you can see below my app.js  file  , because the website im coding contains numerous components, the importing part of the files is overwhelmingly has many lines , as a newbie to Reactjs i wanna ask if there is a more better and professional way to import all the components using less code. thanks

```
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/Navbar";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Socials from "./pages/Socials";
import ToolsServices from "./pages/ToolsServices";
import Marketplace from "./pages/Marketplace";
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound";
import Locations from "./pages/Locations";
import CryptoIndex from "./pages/CryptoIndex";
import AllContextProviders from "./store/AllContextProviders";
```

Comment: You could aggregate them, and then use `import { Navbar, Home, Socials, /*...*/ AllContextProviders } from 'aggregate'`, but just folding the imports in your IDE and not further caring about the issue may be just enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think that is common. I don't know what IDE you're using and WebStorm, the IDE I'm using, allows programmers to fold these "import lines".

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty common to have multiple imports in this way. Generally in teams i've worked with we try to keen it in alphabetical order and also separate imports from node-modules to imports from src files.